# How do I get the "data-name" attribute to the button function?

Tags: jquery, button

Body:

## Movie Search

```
<!-- Movies will get dumped here -->
<div id="movies-view"></div>

<form id="movie-form">
  <label for="movie-input">Add a Movie Bro</label>
  <input type="text" id="movie-input">
  <br>

  <!-- Button triggers new movie to be added -->
  <input id="add-movie" type="submit" value="Add a Movie Bro">
</form>
<div id="movie-view"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
  var movies = ["The Matrix", "The Notebook", "Mr. Nobody", "The Lion King"];
  function renderButtons() {

    $("#movies-view").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {

      var a = $("<button>");

      a.addClass("movie");

      a.attr("data-name", movies[i]);

      a.text(movies[i]);

      $("#movies-view").append(a);

    }

  }
  // This function handles events where the add movie button is clicked
  $("#add-movie").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var movie = $("#movie-input").val();
    movies.push(movie);
    renderButtons();
    var queryURL = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + movie + "&y=&plot=short&apikey=trilogy";

     $.ajax({
      url:queryURL,
      method: "GET"
    }).then(function(response){
        $("#movie-view").text(JSON.stringify(response));

    })
  });

  $(".movie").on("click", function(event){
        var film = $(".movie").attr("data-name");

        var queryURL = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + film + "&y=&plot=short&apikey=trilogy";

        $.ajax({
        url:queryURL,
        method: "GET"
        }).then(function(response){
          $("#movie-view").text(JSON.stringify(response));

        })
  });
  renderButtons();
```

//I want the film data on the "movie-view" div to come after hitting the film title button, not the "Add a Movie bro" button. But I cannot figure out how to put the "data-name" attribute to the ".movie" button. My main question how do I properly write out the variable "film." What needs to go inside of it to get what I am looking for? It seems like everything on it is fine, but

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(".movie").on("click", function(event) { })` ...though note that you'll need to wrap your `.on()` function inside of a `$(document).ready(function() { })`, as your four initial elements are created before the DOM is ready. You'll also need to make use of event delegation with something like `$("body").on("click", ".movie", function(event) { })` to be able to trigger the click of the buttons that get added dynamically.

This can be seen working in the following:

```js
var movies = ["The Matrix", "The Notebook", "Mr. Nobody", "The Lion King"];

function renderButtons() {
  $("#movies-view").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
    var a = $("<button>");
    a.addClass("movie");
    a.attr("data-name", movies[i]);
    a.text(movies[i]);
    $("#movies-view").append(a);
  }
}

// This function handles events where the add movie button is clicked
$("#add-movie").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var movie = $("#movie-input").val();
  movies.push(movie);
  renderButtons();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".movie", function(event) {
    var film = $(this).attr("data-name");
    var queryURL = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + film + "&y=&plot=short&apikey=trilogy";
    $.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: "GET"
    }).then(function(response) {
      $("#movie-view").text(JSON.stringify(response));
    })
  });
});

renderButtons();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Movies will get dumped here -->
<div id="movies-view"></div>

<form id="movie-form">
  <label for="movie-input">Add a Movie Bro</label>
  <input type="text" id="movie-input">
  <br>

  <!-- Button triggers new movie to be added -->
  <input id="add-movie" type="submit" value="Add a Movie Bro">
</form>
<div id="movie-view"></div>
```